# VIM vs NEOVIM vs SpaceVIM

Tags: neovim, spacevim

I am giving Vim a go using WSL. But should I go for Vim or NeoVim or SpaceVim? What are the differences in these, are there any other such variants, and which one should I choose as a starting point?

Comment: I think you are being downvoted because you should be able to get a lot of information and answers to your question by simply searching. Search for Vim vs neovim will give plenty, and the homepage of SpaceVim should give an explanation of what it is. Your question is too broad to get good answers. Instead, after searching and trying to learn, come back and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I’ve closed the question because it contains several questions. Some of them are also opinion-based (« should I go for … », « which one should I choose »). See the linked Q&A in the answer for a good way to ask about the differences (though lets try to avoid duplicating that question: you might ask « what is spacevim and how does it differ from vim/neovim? »)

Comment: I neutralized the downvote, which is my oath "to not let any question be 'mocked' or 'seen as retrograde'.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a contentious issue. In my opinion you might recieve more passionate responses that constructive ones (My answer should not be taken as 100% objective).

For the difference between Vim and Neovim, there was a post [there](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-is-neovim-how-is-it-different-from-vim-and-why-should-i-care).

For the difference with Spacevim, you can see in the main page of their [site](https://spacevim.org). From what I understood, it's like a wrapper that tends to be more user/beginner friendly and facilitates plugins management (you must have Vim, Neovim or Gvim pre-installed).

There is also a project called [Onivim](https://onivim.io). It is maintained by a group of vim/vscode fans. It tends to bring the better of those editors

As a classic Vim-user I think the choice depends of your objectives:

- If you are seeking for knowledge and want to be at ease with any variants of Vim. It's better to start with Vi/Vim
- If you want a Vim that is a few steps ahead of their release, try Neovim
- If you want an IDE-like Vim that works out of the box, it's better to use SpaceVim (you can also find about Onivim)

You can also try the 3 of them with your own usecases to see what is a better fit to you.

Comment: I guess that SpaceVim and other "wrappers", and even any other's configurations or "top 100 best Vim plugins sets" are very bad idea for beginner Vim users.

Comment: Personnally, I think the same. Those "modern" versions are indeed well written and easy to use but I think they are hidding one of the true potentials of vim. Vim is difficult to use at the beginning because it makes the user better (e.g. we learn to think about the text differently and we are educated to know our tools well). Nevertheless, vim is a free software and anyone can do what they want with it (that's the beauty of an open source software). It is better to make one's own experiences and build one's own opinion.